# Understanding ASM. Why does this work in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, assembly

Me and a couple of friends are fiddling with a very strange issue. We encountered a Crash in our application inside of a small assembler portion (used to speed up the process). The error was caused by fiddling with the stackpointer and not resetting it at the end, it looked like this:

```
push        ebp
mov         ebp, esp

; do stuff here including sub and add on esp

pop         ebp
```

When correctly it should be written as:

```
push        ebp
mov         ebp, esp

; do stuff here including sub and add on esp
mov         esp,ebp
pop         ebp
```

Now what our mindbreak is: Why does this work in Windows? We found the error as we ported the application to Linux, where we encountered the crash. Neither in Windows or Android (using the NDK) we encountered any issues and would never have found this error. Is there any Stackpointer recovery? Is there a protection against misusing the stackpointer?

Comment: Are the modifications to `esp` supposed to balance out?  If the `add`s and `pop`s balance out the `sub`s and `push`es, then `esp == ebp` already, then you should leave out the `mov esp, ebp` (because it's not needed).  If it crashes, then obviously they're not balancing out.  Do you use the same assembler on Windows and Linux?  Different assemblers will assemble the same source to different code.  (e.g. in NASM, `mov reg, symbol` is `mov reg, imm32`, but in MASM it's a load.)  The ABIs are also slightly different even for 32bit.

Comment: Is this assembler in a separate file or is it inlined?

Comment: @PeterCordes: No, they do not balance out. Under Linux my Stackpointer is completely bugged

Comment: Well what happens under Windows, when you single step?  At what point does `esp` get back in sync?  Are you sure your source code assembles the same when you build it for Windows?

Comment: if it wasn't inlined, then i'd be curious how you declared the function. was it done with a `funcname PROC C` statement? What was the `model` statement at the top of the assembler file (if it wasn't inlined assembly). what would really help is more information like a minimal complete verifiable example with exact code that works under Windows and the equivalent code you wrote when porting to Linux that failed. as it is I don't believe there is enough information to adequately answer this question. any answer would be guessing.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: The questiuon was answered. in a logical manner. So it seems to me as if there were enough informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ebp esp usage, is called a stack frame, and its purpose is to allocate variables on the stack, and afterward have a quick way to restore the stack back before the `ret` instruction. All new versions of x86 CPU can compress these instructions together using enter / leave instructions instead.

esp is the actual stack pointer used by the CPU when doing push/pop/call/ret.
ebp is a user-manipulated base pointer, more or less all compilers use this as a stack-pointer for local storage.

If the `mov esp, ebp` instruction is missing, the stack will misbehave if esp != ebp when the CPU reaches `pop ebp`, but only then.

Comment: `-fomit-frame-pointer` has been the default in gcc and clang for 32bit x86 for at least a year.  It's been the default in x86-64 for longer.  `enter` / `leave` were new in 80186, so *all* 32bit-capable x86 CPUs support them, not just new ones.  `enter` is way too slow to use, though.  `leave` is worth using if the `mov esp, ebp` part of its operation is needed, otherwise just `pop ebp` if the function body already restores `esp` with an `add` so it can `pop` other regs before `ebp`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the compiler takes care of your stack in windows:
The only way I can imagine is:
Microsoft Visual C takes special care of functions that are B{__stdcall}. Since the number of parameters is known at compile time, the compiler encodes the parameter byte count in the symbol name itself.
The __stdcall convention is mainly used by the Windows API, and it's a bit more compact than __cdecl. The main difference is that any given function has a hard-coded set of parameters, and this cannot vary from call to call like it can in C (no "variadic functions").
see:
http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html
and:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: If his function doesn't pop the args with `ret 8` or something, there's no way a `__stdcall` would work.  A mismatch between caller and callee here would cause breakage, not prevent it.  I don't think it's plausible for this to explain even a case where you got lucky and broken code happened to work in one specific case.

Comment: yes, I agree, in assembly mismatch between caller and callee here would cause breakage.